# Updating a label from another class

Tags: python, android, testing, kivy

When I press the button *save* in `AddTask` class, the text which is in the text input will directly be updated to the *Label* which is in the `Details` class.

#### kivy.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from KivyCalendar import DatePicker
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from database import DataBase
from database2 import DataBase2
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (300,600)
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '300')


Builder.load_file('window.kv')


class HalamanUtama(Screen):
    def submit (self):
        name = self.ids.TaskName.text
        self.ids.task_one.text = name

    def next(self):
        layout = self.ids['invoices']
        arr = db.get_data()
        for invoice in arr:
            lab1 = Label(text=invoice, size_hint_x=.35, halign='left')
            layout.add_widget(lab1)


class AddTask(Screen):
    names = ObjectProperty(None)
    desc = ObjectProperty(None)
    deadline = ObjectProperty(None)
    reminder1 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def submit(self):
        if self.names.text != "" and self.desc.text != "" and self.deadline.text != "" and self.reminder1.text != "":

            db.add_task(self.names.text, self.desc.text, self.deadline.text, self.reminder1.text)
            self.reset()
            hu = HalamanUtama()
            return hu.next()

        else:
            invalidForm()

    def reset(self):
        self.names.text = ""
        self.desc.text = ""
        self.deadline.text = ""
        self.reminder1.text = ""

    def update_value(self, inst):
        """ Update textinput value on popup close """
        self.text = "%s-%s-%s" % tuple(self.cal.active_date)
        self.focus = False
        App.get_running_app().root.ids.deadline.text = self.text

    def show_calendar(self):
        datePicker.show_popup(1, .3)


class DetailTask(Screen):
    def btn(self):
        shows = Delete()

        popupWindow = Popup(title="Delete Task", content=shows, separator_height=0, size_hint=(None, None),
                            size=(230, 230))
        popupWindow.open()


class UncompletedExam(Screen):
    def next(self):
        layout = self.ids['idk']
        arr = db2.get_data()
        for Idk in arr:
            lab2 = Label(text=Idk, size_hint_x=.35, halign='left')
            layout.add_widget(lab2)

class AddExam(Screen):
    namess = ObjectProperty(None)
    descc = ObjectProperty(None)
    deadlinee = ObjectProperty(None)
    reminder11 = ObjectProperty(None)


    def submit(self):
        if self.namess.text != "" and self.descc.text != "" and self.deadlinee.text != "" and self.reminder11.text != "":

            db2.add_exam(self.namess.text, self.descc.text, self.deadlinee.text, self.reminder11.text)
            self.reset()
            ue = UncompletedExam()
            return ue.next()

        else:
            invalidForm()

    def update_value(self, inst):
        """ Update textinput value on popup close """
        self.text = "%s-%s-%s" % tuple(self.cal.active_date)
        self.focus = False
        App.get_running_app().root.ids.deadlinee.text = self.text

    def show_calendar(self):
        datePicker.show_popup(1, .3)

    def reset(self):
        self.namess.text = ""
        self.descc.text = ""
        self.deadlinee.text = ""
        self.reminder11.text = ""

class DetailExam(Screen):
    pass

class WindowsManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Delete(Screen):
    pass


class ListYPP(App):
    def build(self):
        return WindowsManager()

    def vibrate(self, time):
        vibrator.vibrate(time=5)

    def pattern(self, pattern):
        vibrator.pattern([0, 0, 1, 2])

    def exists(self):
        return self._exists()

    def cancel(self):
        self._cancel()

        # private

    def _vibrate(self, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def _pattern(self, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def _exists(self, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def _cancel(self, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()

def invalidLogin():
    pop = Popup(title='Invalid Login',
                content=Label(text='Invalid username or password.'),
                size_hint=(None, None), size=(300, 300))
    pop.open()


def invalidForm():
    pop = Popup(title='Invalid Form',
                content=Label(text='Please fill in all inputs with valid information.', font_size= 14.7),
                size_hint=(None, None), size=(300, 300))

    pop.open()

db2 = DataBase2("examdetail.txt")
db = DataBase("taskdetail.txt")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ListYPP().run()
```

#### database.py

```
import datetime
from KivyCalendar import DatePicker
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '300')

class DataBase:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.taskdetails = None
        self.file = None
        self.load()

    def load(self):
        self.file = open(self.filename, "r")
        self.taskdetails = {}

        for line in self.file:
            taskname, desc, deadline, reminder1 = line.strip().split(";")
            self.taskdetails[taskname] = (desc, deadline, reminder1)
        self.file.close()

    def add_task(self, taskname, desc, deadline, reminder1):
        if taskname.strip() not in self.taskdetails:
            self.taskdetails[taskname.strip()] = (desc.strip(), deadline.strip(), reminder1.strip())
            self.save()
            return 1
        else:
            print("Task Name exists already")
            return -1

    def get_data(self):
        FullDetails = self.taskdetails
        return FullDetails

    def save(self):
        with open(self.filename, "w") as f:
            for detail in self.taskdetails:
                f.write(detail + ";" + self.taskdetails[detail][0] + ";" + self.taskdetails[detail][1] + ";" + self.taskdetails[detail][2] + "\n")

    @staticmethod
    def get_date():
        return str(datetime.datetime.now()).split(" ")[0]
```

#### database2.py

```
import datetime

class DataBase2:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.examdetails = None
        self.file = None
        self.load()

    def load(self):
        self.file = open(self.filename, "r")
        self.examdetails = {}

        for line in self.file:
            examname, descc, deadlinee, reminder11 = line.strip().split(";")
            self.examdetails[examname] = (descc, deadlinee, reminder11)
        self.file.close()

    def add_exam(self, examname, descc, deadlinee, reminder11):
        if examname.strip() not in self.examdetails:
            self.examdetails[examname.strip()] = (descc.strip(), deadlinee.strip(), reminder11.strip())
            self.save()
            return 1
        else:
            print("Exam Name exists already")
            return -1

    def get_data(self):
        FullDetails = self.examdetails
        return FullDetails

    def save(self):
        with open(self.filename, "w") as f:
            for detail in self.examdetails:
                f.write(detail + ";" + self.examdetails[detail][0] + ";" + self.examdetails[detail][1] + ";" + self.examdetails[detail][2] + "\n")

    @staticmethod
    def get_date():
        return str(datetime.datetime.now()).split(" ")[0]
```

#### windows.kv

```
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

<WindowsManager>:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    HalamanUtama:
    AddTask:
    DetailTask:
    UncompletedExam:
    AddExam:
    DetailExam:
    Delete:

<HalamanUtama>:
    name : "halamanutama"
    invoices:invoices

    FloatLayout:
        Image:
            source: 'REVISI TASK.jpg'
            pos_hint:{'left':1, 'top':1}
            size_hint : 1,1
            allow_stretch : True
            keep_ratio : False

    GridLayout:
        id: invoices
        cols: 1
        #orientation: "horizontal"
        padding : 5, 5
        spacing: 10, 10
        #size: 100, 50
        size_hint: 1, 0.7
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.440}


        Button:
            text: ""
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0,0,0,1
                Line:
                    width: 1
                    rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
            color: 0,0,0,1
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'middle'

        Button:
            text: ""
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0,0,0,1
                Line:
                    width: 1
                    rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
            color: 0,0,0,1
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'middle'

        Button:
            text: ""
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0,0,0,1
                Line:
                    width: 1
                    rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
            color: 0,0,0,1
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'middle'

        Button:
            text: ""
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0,0,0,1
                Line:
                    width: 1
                    rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
            color: 0,0,0,1
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'center'
```

But it is not working. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Your kv-file seems malformed. Could not reproduce. It fails with `kivy.lang.parser.ParserException` because `Identifier missing` at line 3 near colon in your  `windows.kv`. Please __fix the kv-file__ and post a [example]. Maybe you could __remove all irrelevant dependencies__, like for example `DataBase`, `DataBase2`, `DatePicker`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with PutExtra for intents

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  *This Example will prove useful if you can understand it and will be easy for you to solve your problem.*

Your main.py

```py
class textinput_screen(widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        supper().__init__(**kwargs)

    def pull_text(self):
       self.text_input = self.ids.ID_text_input.text 
       

class labelupdate_screen(widget):
    text_input_update = StringProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        supper().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text_input_update = textinput_screen.text_input

class theapp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.screenm = ScreenManager()

        self.screen = Screen(name = "text input screem")
        screen.add_widget(self.textinput_screen)

        self.screen = Screen(name = "label update screen")
        screen.add_widget(self.labelupdate_screen)


        self.screenm.add_widget(screen)
if __name__ = "__main__":
    theapp.run()
```

Your kivy file

```py
<textinput_screen>
    ####your widgets####
    TextInput:
        id: Id_text_input
        text_hint: 'text input .... or something'

<labelupdate_screen>
     ####ur widgets#####
     Label:
         Text: root.text_input_update
```

**Note:** *There are many similar questions about this issue. The main reason for this problem is that many people rely too much on kivy-lang, a `text_input(.text)` or a `label(.text)` is considered as widget attribute, if you intend to modify it then re-use it in another widget or a screen then you have to pass it as a variable inside one class or between classes. In this case a `textinput.text` from a class was retrieved by id then was passed to another class as a `stringproperty`.*